# Add and remove data from input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form like this:

```
 <form role="form" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        Description
      </span>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="descr" maxlength="32" placeholder="Optional" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="name_new">
    Add
  </button>
</form>
```

I want to add below it a list of buttons/words (ex: Car, Food, Battery, House), and when the user clicks that word, it gets added in the input field called  "descr" . If he clicks again on that word, it gets removed from the input field

ex: I click Car, Food, House, the Input contains: "car, food, house" .
I click food again, the input contains "car, house"

Also, it would be perfect if after i click pe word/button, it gets forwarded to the start of the list(ex;

car, food, battery, monopoly, money, cards, virgo, website
If i click "cards", the list becomes:
cards, car, food, battery, monopoly, money, virgo, website

If you have any advice on how can I do this with JQuery/Json/javascript, please give me a hint/example.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you have already tried.

Comment: Take a look in this framework: http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: I recommend using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) or a similar modern control to do this type of multi-selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/sgbo3e1s/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $desc = $('.result');
    var selected = [];
    $('.word').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var val = $this.text();
        if($this.hasClass('added')){
            $this.removeClass('added');
            selected.splice($.inArray(val, selected),1);
        }
        else{
            $this.addClass('added');
            selected.unshift(val);
            if(!$this.hasClass('first')){
                $this.insertBefore('.first');
                $('.first').removeClass('first');
                $this.addClass('first');
            }
        }
        $desc.val(selected.join(','));
    });
});
```

Comment: there's a bug somewhere, try this: car-house-company-company-house-car . It adds correctly, but it removes the last word in the list, not the word of that certain button

Comment: you are right, this happens because we I'm not just pushing but also unshifting. I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks Sam. It seems to work like I wanted. A thing I wanted was for the buttons to go to the top when pressed, not the text in the form, but I guess that's harder to do .

Comment: note the css and html changes in the jsfiddle example

Comment: Does not work when both car and cards are in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This code is tested and works

Problems:  when cards is in the text input, and car is added, car would be found in the word cards and and rather than adding car, cards lost the first 3 characters, leaving only the ds.

The above problem was exasperated by the comma requirement.  The added word would be prefaced with `,` (comma space).

If the added word was the first word then it would look like `, word`.

The fixes:

to get rid of the leading comma I used `t.replace(/^, /,'');`  Which replaces a comma at the beginning of the line (^) with '' blank.

to get only the whole word and not a word within another word (car within cards) the boundaries of the word must be included in the removal. A word is preceded with a space or the beginning of the input. The RegEx expression in JavaScript is  "( |^)".  (space or beginning of input)

The word trailing boundary is either a comma or end of input. The regEx is (,|$)

then some inexplicable things would happen after doing rapid add and remove  so I added a couple expression to remove them: ,,  and a hanging comma at the end of the input.

[image]

```
 echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Text</title>
<form role="form" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">Description</span>
<input id="txt" class="form-control" type="text" name="descr" maxlength="32" placeholder="Optional" >
</div></div>
</form>
<button onclick="show('car')">car</button><button onclick="show('food')"> food</button><button onclick="show('battery')"> battery</button><button onclick="show('monopoly')">monopoly</button><button onclick="show('money')">money</button><button onclick="show('cards')"> cards</button><button onclick="show('virgo')"> virgo</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
function show(word){
  var re = new RegExp("( |^)" + word + "($|,)" ,"i");
  if(txt.value.search(re) != -1){
    var str = txt.value;
    str = str.replace(re, "");
    str = str.replace(/,,/gi, ",");
    str = str.replace(/,$/gi, "");
    str = str.replace(/, ,/gi, ",");
    txt.value = str.replace(/,,/gi, ",");
  }
  else{
    var str = txt.value ;
    str.replace(/,/gi, "");
    var t = txt.value + ', ' +  word;
    txt.value = t.replace(/^, /,'');
  }
}
//]]>
</script></body></html>
EOT;
```

Comment: Your code adds the word to the input, but only one word at a time. I need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29154454/4691485 but without that bug.

Comment: It was not easy. When car and cards were both in the list, it created a big problem.  It's working better than the solution you picked as it does not work with car and cards.

Comment: the solution I picked works with words as car and cards . What do you mean ?

Comment: The word car is in cards.  When the app would look for car it would find cards and remove it.  It's no longer an issue, it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way...Assuming the items you click on have class .item. Also, add a class to your input to easily target. Youll also want to pull lin current data, and assign a comma and space to new data.

```
<form role="form" method="POST">
 <div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Description</span>
  <input class="form-control items" type="text" name="descr" maxlength="32" placeholder="Optional" >
  </div>
  </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="name_new">Add</button>
</form>
<a href="" class="item" >Car</a>
<a href="" class="item" >House</a>   


$(".item").on("click", function(e) {
   itemname = $(this).text();
   current = $(".items").val();   
   $(".items").val(current+itemname+", ");
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Your code adds the words, and more then once, this is not ok, and does not remove the word when presseded again.